# why does my linq result show hex values in the debugger?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I noticed when I look at say a result I got back from my database using linq to sql all fields like my primary key that is an auto increment field is shown as hex in my debugger.

So like I will see in the debugger 0x00000006 instead of '6'. Is there any particular reason why? Kinda through me off guard when I wanted to take my result and do a count on it and the count field has 0x00000001 in it and I was checking if it equaled zero.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How the numbers are shown in the debugger is configurable.  Try right clicking on the numbers and unchecking the "Hexidecimal Display" field and it should go back to non-hex values.